# org-babel sbe syntax

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, org-babel

Can anyone give examples of using the `sbe` function in `ob-table.el`?  I must be missing something because I haven't been able to get it to work with straight-up elisp.

```
#+name: add1(x=1) :results silent
#+begin_src python
return x + 1
#+end_src
```

This works:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
#+TBLFM: @1$4='(sbe add1 (x $3))
```

But this does not:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(sbe add1 (x 2))
#+end_src
```

> error: Wrong type argument: sequencep, 2

Changing 2 to a list just aggravates it further:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(sbe add1 (x (list 2))
#+end_src
```

> error: Wrong type argument: buffer-or-string-p, 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you're trying to use your named source block outside of tables to call for results.

First of all, your `:results silent` belongs on the `#+begin_src` line and not the `#+name` (only relevant if you ever evaluate that block directly).  I'm switching to emacs-lisp from python simply because I don't have python on this machine so can't evaluate the block otherwise, the function remains equivalent.

```
#+name: add1(x=1)
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent
  (+ x 1)
#+end_src
```

In Org Tables the proper command is the one you used: `#+tblfm: @1$4='(sbe add1 (x $3))`

When using code blocks outside of tables you have to use `#+CALL:` instead (see [Evaluating Code Blocks](http://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-code-blocks.html)).

For example:

```
#+CALL: add1(x=2)

#+RESULTS: add1(x=2)
: 3

#+CALL: add1(4)

#+RESULTS: add1(4)
: 5

#+call: add1(add1(2))

#+RESULTS: add1(add1(2)
: 4
```

---

Edit (Adding in answer from comment):

If you simply want to clean up your formulas and be better able to read through them to make changes, the formula editor `C-c '` will let you see them more clearly as well as highlight cell references to ensure you're selecting the right regions.

Comment: Actually, I was hoping to call my source block "functions" directly from emacs lisp because my `#+TBLFM` lines were getting a little long.

Comment: @wdkrnls Where were you hoping to call them?  If it's part of a table you add them to `#+TBLFM:` if it's elsewhere in your document you use `#+CALL:`

Comment: I just wanted to compress my `#+TBLFM:` line by wrapping operations up into more meaningfully named functions.  I know I can do this with emacs-lisp, but I'd like to be able to do it with other languages to.

Comment: @wdkrnls Would using the table formula editor `C-c '` help with regards to your `#+TBLFM:` line?  It won't clear up the line itself, however it will make it easier to edit them and read what they're doing